# VIM - Sourcing tags from multiple locations in project

Tags: vim, vi, ctags, code-completion, omnicomplete

Good day,

I typically work on relatively small (less than 20,000 lines of code) projects that are all self contained within a single directory, have their own Makefile, and are fairly easy to work with.

VIM is my preferred editor, and when I open a project, I typically build the ctags list via a mapping to the <kbd>F10</kbd> key:

```
map <F10> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
```

This allows me to jump to the definition of a variable/struct/etc via moving the cursor over the text, and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, as well as using code completion with a drop-down list via OmniCppComplete.

However, I am now working on a slightly larger project which makes use of LOTS of structures. Furthermore, many of these structures have arrays of other custom structures as members, so code completion is a very useful and important tool for me right now.

I have two paths that include a lot of `.C` files and `.h` files, and they may change from machine to machine. On each machine, however, we have an environment variable in our `.bashrc` file that points to them like so:

```
SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS=/public/sdk
THIRD_PARTY_SDK=/private/sdk
```

I would like to be able to have VIM automatically refer to the contents of these additional paths when I attempt to do code completion (via VIM's built-in OmniCppComplete feature), or to jump to the files in these locations when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> in VIM to jump to the definition of a struct, function, variable, etc.

So, for both of the above paths, I `cd` into them, and generate the tags via `ctags -R`. Then, I modified my `~/.vimrc` file to include additional tags paths, like so:

```
tags=./tags
tags+=$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags
tags+=$THIRD_PARTY_SDK/tags
```

I then `cd` into my project at `/home/user1/projects/test`, start VIM, and hit <kbd>F10</kbd> in VIM to index it. However, this does not work at all. In fact, it breaks my ability to even use tags just for the project itself (ie: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> now does nothing).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could have code completion source tags and jump-to-definitions using multiple source directories via environment variables?

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: Hmmm this has always worked for me. Have you checked the value of tags using `:verbose set tags?`?

Comment: @sehe Affirmative. I have checked the output via the above command, and the result is: `tags=./tags,$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags,$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags`. I'm wondering if it might be something as simple as my syntax for the BASH environment variables (ie: maybe I need to use some sort of VIM function to dereference the environment variables and reduce them to an absolute path?).

Comment: Yeah, if it's not expanded, I'd wager only ~ is supported

Comment: @sehe Do you know what command I could use in my VIMRC to expand the environment variables at VIM startup? I'm not really allowed to modify the VIMRC to use a sentinel path string; it has to use the env vars.

Comment: In fact, I already posted that in case you weren't noticing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed appears to be the problem that you can't use environment variables inside the tags setting.

I came up with this as a workaround:

```
:let &tags.=expand(",$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags")
```

This might be slightly more friendly:

```
:exec expand("set tags+=$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags")
```

Comment: Hm, `:help 'tags'` says _Environment variables are expanded |:set_env|._

Comment: Hm. Yeah. It looks as if you're right. However, that's not what happened on my windows box, IIRC - I checked it. I'll see whether I can try again later

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to the solution provided by @sehe.

This is the final set of changes I made to my `.vimrc`. The first lines are for adding expanded environment variable paths to my `tags` variable. The other is for auto-updating tags in the event that I have to update my SDK and don't want to be able to accidentally use out-of-date tags:

```
" CTAGS tag generation for OmniCppComplete
set tags+=./tags
exec expand("set tags+=$SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags")
exec expand("set tags+=$THIRD_PARTY_SDK/tags")
" Can verify taglist is correct via ":set verbose tags?" command

" Create a mapping to delete the old tags, re-generate them, and use them
map <F10> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q . \| rm -f $SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags \| ctags -R -f $SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags $SDK_SRC_PLUS_HEADERS/tags  \| rm -f $THIRD_PARTY_SDK/tags \| ctags -R -f $THIRD_PARTY_SDK/tags $THIRD_PARTY_SDK/tags  \| echo "Done re-generating tags."<CR>
```